# MySQL trigger for updating a particular record column value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have been tried mysql trigger to set a field to value 1, if there is any update action happened in any column of the record.

I am newbie in trigger, so help me to set a value to 1, if updated record

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classic usecase for a `before update` trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_upd_trg 
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.special_field = 1;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TRIGGER t_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name

SET @attribute_name = 1;